# When starting edit form getting "error converting a character to a number error of a number or value" for PK List Of Value

Tags: primary-key, oracle19c, oracle-apex-5

I have a List of Values called "BOOK.NAME ", backed by the following SQL:

```
select book."id_book", book."Name" from "Book" book;
```

This LoV returns "id_book" and displays "Name".

When I display this LoV instead of id_book in Interactive Report, everything works fine.
When I run the form for creating a new record, where id_book is the Primary Key together with another attribute "id_delivery_to_storage", the values from LoV are also substituted normally. However, when I run the same form, but already to change the current record, I get an error:

> ora_sqlerrm: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: : error converting a character to a number error of a number or value

As I understand it, it must have something to do with the fact that this field is Primary or with the fact that it is Primary paired with another Primary field, however, I have no idea how to fix it. Please tell me what needs to be changed to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know whether it has (or has not) anything to do with a primary key, but what you said isn't true.

> ```
> select book."id_book", book."Name" from "Book" book;
> ```
>
> This LoV returns "id_book" and displays "Name".

LoV query in Apex has the following format:

```
select display_value, return_value
from ...
```

which is **opposite** of what you claim. Usually (if not always); we display "names" and return "IDs" - I suggest you do the same and "reverse" your code to

```
select book."Name"    as display_value,
       book."id_book" as return_value
from "Book" book
```

Also, make sure that you're passing the ID to the form.

---

Not related to this question, but: don't use double quotes and mixed letter case in Oracle. If you do, you always have to use double quotes and match letter case. Will you always remember that the *name* is written with a capital "N", while the *ID* is written in lower case?